# facing problem to fix component left and right side positions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

i am working on a small component i am facing issue to control moving div. i want to stop moving div when it reaches at left or right side or other words it should stop when left or right position == 0;

i am working on a small component i am facing issue to control moving div. i want to stop moving div when it reaches at left or right side or other words it should stop when left or right position == 0;

```js
var leftDivWidth  = $('#left').width()/2;
applyRect = $('#left').css('clip', 'rect(0px,' + leftDivWidth + 'px, auto,0px)');
var isResizing = false,
lastDownX = 0;
$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');
    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientX;
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;
         var offsetRight = e.clientX - container.offset().left;
            if($(handle).left == 0){
                alert('working');
            }
         handle.css('left', offsetRight);
         left.css('clip', 'rect(0px,' + offsetRight + 'px,auto,0px)')
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
#container #left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    /*clip: rect(0px, 50%, 484px, 0px);*/
}
#container #handle {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa{
 font-family: fontawesome;
    line-height: 52px;
}
#left img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}
#right img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div id="container">
        <div id="right">
            <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/astronaut_neon_art_148365_1920x1080.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- Left side -->
        <div id="left"> 
         <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/astronaut_ring_neon_156673_1920x1080.jpg">
        </div>
     <div class="innerDiv">
         <div id="handle"> <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> </div>
     </div>
        <!-- Right side -->
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just match it with the `parentOffsetWidth` and to lock movement just create flag `lockMovement` and simply set it to true when the conditon meets.

```js
var leftDivWidth  = $('#left').width()/2;
applyRect = $('#left').css('clip', 'rect(0px,' + leftDivWidth + 'px, auto,0px)');
var isResizing = false;
var lockMovement = false;
lastDownX = 0;
$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');
    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        if(!lockMovement){
           isResizing = true;
           lastDownX = e.clientX;
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;
         var offsetRight = e.clientX - container.offset().left;
            if($(handle)[0].offsetLeft >= $(handle)[0].offsetParent.offsetWidth){ //========> match the parent offsetwidth with the child offsetLeft
                alert('working');
                isResizing = false;
                lastDownX=0;
                lockMovement =true;
            }
         handle.css('left', offsetRight);
         left.css('clip', 'rect(0px,' + offsetRight + 'px,auto,0px)')
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
          isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
#container #left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    /*clip: rect(0px, 50%, 484px, 0px);*/
}
#container #handle {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa{
 font-family: fontawesome;
    line-height: 52px;
}
#left img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}
#right img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div id="container">
        <div id="right">
            <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/astronaut_neon_art_148365_1920x1080.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- Left side -->
        <div id="left"> 
         <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/astronaut_ring_neon_156673_1920x1080.jpg">
        </div>
     <div class="innerDiv">
         <div id="handle"> <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> </div>
     </div>
        <!-- Right side -->
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can stop when it touch left or right side.

Comment: what do you mean? its locking the movmenet as you asked. you can see the code snippet i attached.

Comment: i am saying when it touch to left or right side it stop moving

Comment: it stops moving. Isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: please scroll down the page and check the section 
DRIVING TAKES ON A NEW DIMENSION IN THE ALL-NEW PEUGEOT 2008

https://www.peugeot.co.uk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210989/discussion-between-mr-khan-and-saira).

Answer (score 0):

Just add offset() to if-statement:

```js
            if($(handle).left <= 0){
                alert('working');
            }
```

```js
            if($(handle).offset().left <= 0){
                alert('working');
            }
```

And it's better to use <= than strict == equation.